# Unable to click on City bubble on Google map using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have been trying to click on City bubble on Google Map.
So far I have tried following but none seems to work. Also notice the awkward locator available from map which is captured in Selenium IDE

```
<tr>
<td>clickAt</td>
<td>//div[@id='map']/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/canvas</td>
<td>586, 190</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
<td>mouseDownAt</td>
<td>//div[@id='map']/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/canvas</td>
<td>586, 190</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseUpAt</td>
<td>//div[@id='map']/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/canvas</td>
<td>586, 190</td>
</tr>
```

But none of these seem to work. Has any one been able to click on a specific position like city bubble using Selenium

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but shouldn't you be using the javascript googlemaps api instead of dom elements? There is even an open source selenium testsuite for it.

See http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/SeleniumTests

And http://gmaps-api-issues.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/selenium/core/TestRunner.html?test=../tests/stable_suite.html

Comment: had seen these selenium tests in past and I thought they are also using DOM. java script Google Map API - looks interesting, let me see this... and yes +1 to you